# Как сравнить массив со значениями предыдущих массивов?

Tags: javascript

С сервера приходит `JSON` с массивами заказов, в которых указаны номера услуг. 
Каждый массив это отдельный заказ. Для каждого массива нужно проверить нет ли дублей номеров услуг в предыдущих массивах. Т.е. второй массив нужно сравнить с первым. Третий сравнить с первым и вторым и т.д.

```
   {[56,90,45],[23,26,97],[85,12,40]}
```

Дубликаты потом будут дополнительно обрабатываться.
В рамках массива дублей не будет.

Comment: Что делать если дубликаты есть ?

Comment: а дубли в рамках массива возможны?

Answer (score 0):

> Для каждого массива нужно проверить нет ли дублей номеров услуг в
>   предыдущих массивах. Т.е. второй массив нужно сравнить с первым.
>   Третий сравнить с первым и вторым и т.д.

Думаю, что условие вполне можно упростить до "ни один элемент не должен повторяться".

Я предложу на выбор два способа выполнить такую проверку:

1. если не нужно никакой дополнительной модификации исходных данных - просто склеиваем все массивы с помощью [метода concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) в один и любым проходом по получившемуся списку (filter, reduce и проч.) находим дубликаты.
2. если модификация исходных данных таки нужна то сделаем это с помощью [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

**1 способ, просто поищем дубликаты**:

```js
let json = [[56, 90, 45, 40],[23, 56, 26, 97],[85, 12, 40]];

let doubles0 = [].concat.apply([], json).filter((x, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(x) !== i);

let doubles1 = [].concat.apply([], json).reduce((acc, x, i, arr) => {
  if (arr.indexOf(x) !== i) {
    acc.push(x);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(doubles0);
console.log(doubles1);
```

**2 способ, поищем дубликаты не меняя структуру исходных данных и, для разнообразия, сохраним координаты дубля и первого входжения**:

```js
let json = [[56, 90, 45, 40],[23, 56, 26, 97],[85, 12, 40]];
let {doubles} = json.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
  let {uniq, doubles} = acc;

  x.forEach((o, j) => {
    if (!uniq.has(o)) {
      uniq.set(o, [i, j]);
    } else {
      console.log(`double: o (${uniq.get(o)})(${[i,j]})`);
      doubles.push([o, [i, j], uniq.get(o)]);
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, {uniq: (new Map()), doubles: []});

console.log(doubles);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var array = JSON.parse('[[23,90,45],[23,26,97],[85,12,40]]');

for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
{
 var next = array[i];
 //Проверка:
 for(var j = 0; j < i; j++)
 {
  var previous = array[j];
  if(next[0] == previous[0] || next[1] == previous[1] || next[2] == previous[2])
   console.log('Элемент массива ' + i + ' имеет одинаковое(-ые) значение(-я) с элементом ' + j);
 }
}
```

Только ещё обратите внимание на то, что у вас неправильный объект, а не массив.

Comment: ужасный ответ. давай поэкспериментируем с `[[1,2,3],[2,3,1]]` или с `[[1,2,3,0],[4,5,6,0]]`

Comment: @norbornen, мой ответ правильный. Видимо вы не поняли вопроса пользователя. Прочтите ещё раз. И почитайте в правилах о дружелюбности, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Bharata Почему Вы считаете,что ответ правильный? Нужно проверить,нет ли дубликатов услуг в предыдущих заказах,так что возможно и так [[1,2,3],[2,3,1]],а еще возможно что кол-во услуг в заказах разное и Ваше решение терпит фиаско.

Comment: @Александр ты тоже недружелюбен! фу таким быть!

Comment: @Bharata, прошу у вас ссылку на страницу правил. Пожалуйста :)

Comment: @norbornen, [Справка > Наша модель > Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: @Bharata благодарю. в чате попросил отредактировать мой комментарий

Answer (score -1):

Всё делаеся в один проход по массиву.

```js
var data = [[23,90,45], [23,26,97], [85,12,40]]
var count = Object.create(null)
var res = [], cur, dups

for (var a of data) {
  res.push(cur = [])

  for (var x of a) {
    if (!++count[x]) {
      cur.push(x)
      count[x] = 1
    }
  }
}

dups = Object.keys(count).filter(x => count[x] > 1).map(Number)

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
console.log(JSON.stringify(dups))
```